# C regex validate filename under a folder

Tags: c, regex, filenames

I am new to regular expressions in C and I am trying to find if the given filename is under a folder using regex using `regex.h` library. This is what I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>

int checkregex(char regex_str[100], char test[100]) {
    regex_t regex;
    printf("regex_str: %s\n\n", regex_str);
    int reti = regcomp(&regex, regex_str, REG_EXTENDED | REG_ICASE);
    if (reti) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    reti = regexec(&regex, test, 0, NULL, REG_EXTENDED | REG_ICASE);
    regfree(&regex);
    return reti;
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *safepath = "/home";
    size_t spl = strlen(safepath);

    char *fn = argv[1];

    int noDoubleDots = checkregex("[^..\\/]", fn);
    int allowedChars = checkregex("^[[:alnum:]\\/._ -]*$", fn);
    int backslashWithSpace = checkregex(".*(\\ ).*", fn);

    puts("noDoubleDots");
    puts((noDoubleDots == 0 ? "Match\n" : "No Match\n"));
    puts("allowedChars");
    puts((allowedChars == 0 ? "Match\n" : "No Match\n"));
    puts("backslashWithSpace");
    puts((backslashWithSpace == 0 ? "Match\n" : "No Match\n"));

    return;
}
```

My first attempt was just do not match if it includes `..` (I couldn't even manage to do it) with `noDubleDots`. But then I tested and saw that file names and folder names can have `..` in them, like `folder..name/`. So I wanted to exclude the ones with `/..` or `../`. But if the folder name is something like `folder ..` and it has another folder inside named `folder2/` then the path will be `folder\ ../folder2` and excluding `../` would result in wrong output.

In the code, allowedChars works fine. I think if I also checked if the file name has exactly `..`, `\ ..` or `\ ([:alnum:])*` to validate the file path, it would be done. But my regular expression doesn't seem to be working. For example, backslashWithSpace matches with `asd /` and `asd\ /`.

How can I check and make sure that the given path is under a folder using regular expressions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do or why you think regexes are a good solution. How are you going to deal with symlinks?

Comment: Basically I am trying to make sure that the path name given to the program is under the home directiory. I had some issues about names containing `..` and spaces so I tried to explain them. I thought that there are some patterns in the path name that I can match, so maybe I can use regexes to find these patterns. I also can ignore the symlinks right now.

Comment: Isn't that just `if (!strstr(fn, "/../"))`? What do you mean by "some issues"?

Comment: I've managed to create a folder named `folder ..`. Doesn't that cause any problem? What confuses me is what am I supposed to do with path names with spaces and `..` in them.

Comment: Your regular expressions look slightly wrong. For one, backslashWithSpace should probably have the backslash escaped, i.e. " \\\\ ". and noDoubleDots seems to match characters not in "./ "

Comment: @MustafaSüve No, `folder ..` is a normal name and doesn't cause problems. You're not supposed to do anything special with path names containing `..` or spaces (except for `..` itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX offer a nice function [`realpath()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html)

> realpath() expands all symbolic links and resolves references to /./,
>   /../ and extra '/' characters in the null-terminated string named by
>   path to produce a canonicalized absolute pathname.  The resulting
>   pathname is stored as a null-terminated string, up to a maximum of
>   PATH_MAX bytes, in the buffer pointed to by resolved_path.  The
>   resulting path will have no symbolic link, /./ or /../ components.

If you can use it, I think it will fit your need, if not maybe you could copy the source code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it helped. But when I have a folder named `folder ..` and inside that folder `folder2 ..`, I can get the real path for the first folder but not for the second folder. Is there any solution to that?

Comment: @MustafaSüve Sorry I didn't understand your exemple.

Comment: I created a folder named `folder ..` with the name folder followed by a space and two dots. Then inside that folder, I created another folder called `folder2 ..` with the name folder2 followed by a space and two dots. I send the path `folder\ ../folder2\ ..` to the realpath function and it only gave me `folder\ ..`. It works fine for other normal situations.

Comment: @MustafaSüve I can't reproduce your bug with http://rextester.com/ERS27337

Comment: When I do `./a "/folder\ ../folder2\ .."` with my code, I printed fn `fn= /folder\ ..`.

Comment: @MustafaSüve `/folder` is completely different of `folder` ! Plus, this must be something with the directory you use, your folder 2 is probably a symbolic link to folder ! `ls -l "/folder ../"` will probably help you.